# Fatal Exception: java.lang.SecurityException without permission com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE

Tags: android, sdk, android-permissions, user-permissions

> Fatal Exception: java.lang.SecurityException: Not allowed to start
>   service Intent { act=com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTER
>   pkg=com.google.android.gms (has extras) } without permission
>   com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE
>          at android.app.ContextImpl.startServiceCommon(ContextImpl.java:1419)
>          at android.app.ContextImpl.startService(ContextImpl.java:1396)
>          at android.content.ContextWrapper.startService(ContextWrapper.java:623)
>          at com.google.firebase.iid.zzat.zze(Unknown Source:130)
>          at com.google.firebase.iid.zzat.zzd(Unknown Source:91)
>          at com.google.firebase.iid.zzat.zzc(Unknown Source:90)
>          at com.google.firebase.iid.zzr.zza(Unknown Source:73)
>          at com.google.firebase.iid.zzs.run(Unknown Source)
>          at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
>          at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
>          at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:760)

Comment: Post your manifest file

Comment: I just integrated firebase crash and analytics SDK, and didn't use anything about FCM, but this problem has happened on many devices, not 100%, but it will happen frequently. I don't know how to locate and fix it

Comment: reference  https://github.com/HanteIsHante/file/issues/62  @RahulChandrabhan

Comment: If you use a filter to intercept it, will you avoid this crash?

Answer (score 0):

This happens when you installed an application that uses GCM before you installed GmsCore. Android was not able to grant the requires permission to the app because it did not know about the permission at all (because it is defined in GmsCore). To work around this issue you can re-install the app that causes the problem (no need to remove it, just install it again).

[android_packages_apps_GmsCore](https://github.com/microg/android_packages_apps_GmsCore)

Comment: I didn't use any operations on GCM, only Firebase's crashlytics and anlytics. I don't understand why this kind of problem with GCM still occurs.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have added Receive permission in your android manifest.

You must also initialize runtime permission in code also it is now mandatory from api 23 and higher

```
if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.RECIEVE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){


        if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this, Manifest.permission.RECIEVE)){
            Toast.makeText(this, "Need Permission.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }else {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.RECIEVE}, MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_RECIEVE);
        }
    }else{  // do noting
    }
```

These are the runtime permissions!

Comment: I have tried to add the following permissions, but there are still many devices that have this problem.

Comment: `<!--FireBase Event -->
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission android:name="${applicationId}.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"/>
<permission
android:name="${applicationId}.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
android:protectionLevel="signature" /> `

Comment: Now I don't know how to deal with it.